# seaborn FacetGrid: plot one category and all the categories

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a pandas datataframe with some data, some columns are categories, in this case (`isPassed`) just a boolean.

I am plotting some histograms, I would like to plot all the entries and to superimpose the one where `isPassed` is True. For example:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=col_quantity, hue="isPassed")
g = g.map(plt.hist, hist_quantity, bins=np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), normed=False)
```

This supeimpose, with different color, the histogram of the `hist_quantity` for entries with `isPassed == 0` and for entries with `isPassed == 1`. As I said I would like to superimpose entries without any check on `isPassed` (`True or False`) and the one with `isPassed == 1`.

Of course there are many ways to do that, but I would like to do with with `FacetGrid`. One solution would be to duplicate the entries and to have `isPassed == 2` for the duplicated ones and to plot the one with `isPassed == 1` and `isPassed == 2`. I don't like this solution, the best solution would be to have the `hue` value to accept a callable, or an expression as `pandas.DataFrame.query`. Other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution, I hope someone has a better one:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=col_quantity)
def p(x, passed, **kwargs):
    bins = kwargs.get('bins', None)
    plt.hist(x, bins=bins, normed=False)
    plt.hist(x[passed == 1], bins=bins, normed=False)
g = g.map(p, hist_quantity, "isPassed", bins=np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
```